# powershell, write-host all filenames of the files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am now better in writing, stealing and modifying scripts but here I am a stuck a little.
My script sums up files in a specific folder and counts them. 
Like this :

```
{
function alljournals 
{
$colItems =  (get-childitem  "$targetfolder" -include *.xlsx* -recurse | measure-object -property length -sum)
write-host "Collected all .xlsx files from all ImportJournal folders" -foregroundcolor "green"
"Number of files: "+ $colItems.count + [Environment]::NewLine + "Size of all files "+"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB" 
}
alljournals
}
```

What's the smartest way to list all files from that folder using write-host? I tried to put a write-host $colitems.Fullname without good results.

I know that I could easily put the files in a loop and than use foreach and display the filename. But for that I have to change everything. So is there a way?

Right now it displays something like that :

```
Collected all .xlsx files from all Importjournalfolders
Number of files 15
Size of all files: 13,3mb
```

What I need before that output is a list of all files with path

Any Ideas or tips ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could capture the list of files in the first pipeline using tee-object, and then use foreach on that.

```
$colItems =  (get-childitem  "$targetfolder" -include *.xlsx* -recurse | tee-object -variable files | measure-object -property length -sum)
$files | foreach-object {write-host $_.FullName}
```

Comment: that's what I wanted my friend :) Thank you!

Comment: BTW, I haven't ever used tee-object except to explain how to use it to others.

Comment: it is working fantastico, I would upvote more if i could